# Migrate from IBM Directory Server 8 to MS Active Directory (Windows Server 2019)

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2019, ibm, passthrough

We are in a project to migrate users and passwords from IBM Directory Server v8 to Microsoft Active Directory. Use of IBM Directory Integrator (LDAPSync) is referenced in official IBM documentation. I wanted to know if someone has had a similar case and what would be the recommendation to carry out the migration keeping the passwords of the users (which are encrypted from the application layer)? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remeber, there was a Password Synchronization for Active Directory Plug-in for IBM Security Identity Governance and IBM Security Directory Server.

Also, there was new thing called LDAPSync, but passwords are not handled by LDAPSync itself.

LDAPSync is (mainly) designed to migrate and synchronize object entries. To handle passwords, you can use the pass-through authentication (of IBM Security Directory Server), which you can configure to migrate passwords as the users authenticate. You can *not* migrate "offline" Users, as the authentication process itself is used to do that.

But the last time I had to do such things was moments after the last dinosaur left earth.